# Tkinter map mouse coordinates to figure size

Tags: python, tkinter, mouseevent

I'm using Tkinter where an ASCII figure is printed on a label. I want it to change depending on where I click with the mouse, but I do not know how to tackle that problem. How would I map the mouse's coordinates so that it is restricted by a range, say [-n, n]? I am printing my mouse's (event.x, event.y) and I need those values restricted by the earlier stated interval. So instead of the values I get by moving my mouse ranging from 300 to 400, how can I map them to range from -15 to 15, for example?

Thank you in advance!

Edit: Here is what the program looks like - the center is the (0, 0) coordinate and I only want to be able to click on the sphere to rotate it. Therefore, I want to have my interval range from [-r, r] when clicking width the mouse.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your intervals. lets assume you have [-15,15], and mouse movement from 0-300, you map -15,15 onto [-150,150], which means that every spatial entity you move your mouse (1/150) is 15/150 = 0.1 step in the scale of your choice [-n,n], which you multiply with your mouse coordinate to get the corresponding value within your range [-n, n]. therefore its n*(n/m) with n being target interval and m being the coordinate interval. Why negative values? You must determine your [0,0] for your coordinate system, and this also depends on whether you want to increase size only or also shrink the figure. Maybe give some additional information or a code snippet!

Comment: I appreciate your response, and thank you for your explanation of the logic behind it! The reason I am using negative values is because I am creating a sphere which has the center (0, 0). So the size of it depends on its radius 'r'. It is hard for me to visualize this, due to the origin in my GUI being the top left corner, whereas the origin of my actual sphere is in the center. The x-values and y-values are negative on the left hand side and right hand side of the sphere respectively.

Comment: I do not fully understand how I would incorporate the formula n*(n/m) - is n supposed to be the size of the interval? Maybe the max, or minimum?

Comment: If you want to adjust size by clicking onto the sphere or GUI, shall the rim of the sphere be relocated onto the point where you clicked? then you need to calculate the vector from the sphere center [0,0] to the coordinates you click, e.g. [20,20] where both x and y range from [0,300] for a GUI with 300*300 pixels. In this GUI coordinate system, your sphere center would be [150,150] when [0,0] is upper left corner. Then you need to convert [20,20] into sphere coordinates which is [-150,150] so [20,20] would be [-130, 130]. The offset between sphere and gui coordinates must be integrated too.

Comment: After determining the offset, you can use n*(n/m) to scale the coordinates